# When I quit Blender, I get: "Blender has stopped working, windows is looking for a solution"

Tags: windows

I had to install a new motherboard, and with it, I had to reinstall my Windows 7 OS.

Everything works well, I had reinstalled Blender also.

When I quit with CTRL+Q or from the menu: File/Quit, I get a windows popup:

```
"Blender has stopped working" 
"Windows is looking for a solution."
```

When I quit by making the console visible (Window/Toggle system console), then closing with the red "X" button, I don't get the message.

How can I make this message go away? It's quite annoying.

Googling shows no results for this problem. I've been using Blender for years (not so much recently), I never had such a problem.

Edit:

hardware: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU 2.80 GHz, 4GB RAM. Motherboard: Asrock G41M-S3

software: 64bit Windows 7 professional

Comment: Have you already installed latest drivers (graphic) and Windows updates?

Comment: First thing was to update my windows, and also I've installed the drivers from the cd which came with the motherboard. (Currently I use the integrated video card)

Comment: the bundled CDs are usually outdated, try to install the latest drivers available online.